# Is there way I can access this arrayList later in my code?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
new ArrayList<Integer>().addAll(Arrays.asList(4,5,6,7));
```

I could write:

```
ArrayList<Integer> my_array = new ArrayList<Integer>().addAll(Arrays.asList(4,5,6,7));
```

How can i access the first array later in my code without creating a reference to it?

Comment: Have a look at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: If I understand it right, you can't! You have to create a reference. I'm pretty sure you can't do that in any language. Again, if I understand it right.

Comment: why you don't want to create reference to it?

Comment: If you only have `new ArrayList<Integer>().addAll(Arrays.asList(4,5,6,7));`, then you can't access this list. See the links provided by @MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code, you are just creating an object. And in the second piece of code, you are creating an object *and* putting it into a variable.

Let's have an analogy here, imagine that objects are like balloons, and the variables are like kids holding the balloons. In your first code, you create a balloon and "Let it go". And it flies away. In the second code though, you create a kid and a balloon and you told the kid to hold it. Now you can ask the kid for the balloon and you can access it.

So long story short, **You cannot access the List in the first code**.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't create a reference, you won't be able to access it. No exceptions that I am aware of.

I suppose you could push that new object into another ArrayList and then use .get() to access it again. No point to that unless you want a list of lists.